# GCP Alert policy MQL query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring, mql

I need to build a GCP alert policy to be triggered if the total amount of a metric from this week is more than x % of the previous week. I think I need to use a conditional threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create both threshold and absence alerting policies with MQL.

You create an MQL-based alerting policy by using one of the following MQL alerting operations in your query:

1. [condition](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#condition-tabop) operation for threshold alerts.
2. [absent_for](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#absent_for-tabop) operation for absence alerts.

Your query must end with one of these operations. Your query must omit an explicit time-range specification, that is, a within operation.

For threshold alerts, use the condition operation. The condition operation takes an expression that evaluates a value against a threshold, like "the value is greater than 15 percent", and returns a boolean.

The condition operation requires that the input table be aligned with an explicit alignment window. To align the input table with an explicit window, specify an alignment window to an [align](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#align-tabop) operation—for example, align delta_gauge(5m)—or use a temporal group_by with a sliding time window. The following example illustrates using group_by with a [sliding](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#sliding-func) operation:

```
fetch gce_instance::compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization
| filter zone =~ 'us-central.*'
| group_by sliding(5m), mean(val())
| condition val() > .15 '10^2.%'
```

Refer the document on [Creating alert policies with MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/alerts) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks Fariya for the answer, that works fine with a small window but the alert policy gave me this error, and seems like it doesn't support more than 24 hours. 'This MQL-Bases alert policy condition requires 168h of data, but alerting can only query for up to 24h of data.

Comment: @Razmin What  kind of service are you using is it free or paid one ? You need to upgrade if you feel you need that extra capacity and features. Refer to this [document](https://www.impactplus.com/blog/is-google-analytics-free) for more information.